# Correlationmatrix vs. OLS Statsmodels (Difference R² and Correlation coeffiicient)

Tags: regression, correlation

When I pick the highest correlation fatcor in my heatmap this does not
necessesarly result in the best R² when calculated with statsmodels smf.

On the other hand an input a vriable which has an equal correlation coeffiecint results in a better R². How can this behvaiour be explained? Why does not the highest correlated feature results in the highest R²?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you regressing on a single explanatory variables or on multiple? In multiple regression with non-orthogonal designs, there is no direct link between simple correlation and contribution to rsquared because of the correlation between explanatory variables.

Comment: Only one variable and the number is completley different.